# passing props of list type to the child component is getting one item added to the list by default -Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have two components A and B which are contained in the Component C. I add an item from B to the list in the parent component C and pass the list to the component A. However one item is getting added to the list automatically on page load (when the component C gets rendered). I am using props to pass the list from parent component C to child Component A.

Parent Component (C)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <contact-summary :contacts="contacts"> </contact-summary>
    <contact-detail @submittedContact="submittedContact"></contact-detail>

  </div>
</template>
<script>
import ContactDetails from "./ContactDetails.vue";
import ContactSummary from "./ContactSummary.vue";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      contacts:[ {
        businessName: null,
        contactPerson: null,
        address: null,
        contactNumber: null,
        selectedCategory: null
      }],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    submittedContact(contact) {
      console.log(contact);
      this.contacts.push(contact);
    }
  },
  components: {
    "contact-detail": ContactDetails,
    "contact-summary": ContactSummary
  }
};
</script>
```

Component B

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h3>Contact Details</h3>
    <hr />
    <form method="post">
      <div v-if="errors.length">
        <b>Please correct the following error(s):</b>
        <ul>
          <li class="text-danger" v-for="error in errors" :key="error">{{ error }}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label>Business Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            v-model="contact.businessName"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label>Contact Person</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            v-model="contact.contactPerson"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
          <label>Address</label>
          <textarea
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            v-model="contact.address"
          ></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label>Contact Number</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            v-model="contact.contactNumber"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label>Category of Business</label>
          <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
            <option
              v-for="category in category"
              :key="category.categoryCode"
              :selected="(contact.selectedCategory = category.categoryText)"
              >{{ category.categoryText }}</option
            >
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <button class="btn btn-primary" @click.prevent="submitRequest">
        Submit Contact
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      errors: [],
      contact: {
        businessName: null,
        contactPerson: null,
        address: null,
        contactNumber: null,
        selectedCategory: null
      },
      category: [
        {
          categoryText: "Food",
          categoryCode: 1
        },
        {
          categoryText: "Medicine",
          categoryCode: 2
        },
        {
          categoryText: "Shop",
          categoryCode: 3
        },
        {
          categoryText: "Housekeeping",
          categoryCode: 4
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    submitRequest(e) {

      if(this.checkForm())
      {
      this.$emit("submittedContact", this.contact);
      this.contact = {};
      this.errors = [];
      }
      else{
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    },
    checkForm(e) {
      if (
        this.contact.businessName &&
        this.contact.contactPerson &&
        this.contact.contactNumber &&
        this.contact.address &&
        this.contact.selectedCategory
      ) {
        return true;
      }
      this.errors = [];
      if (!this.contact.businessName) {
        this.errors.push("Business Name Required");
      }
      if (!this.contact.contactPerson) {
        this.errors.push("Contact Person Required");
      }
      if (!this.contact.contactNumber) {
        this.errors.push("Contact Number Required");
      }
      if (!this.contact.address) {
        this.errors.push("Address Required");
      }
      if (!this.contact.selectedCategory) {
        this.errors.push("Category Required");
      }

    }
  }
};
</script>
<style scoped></style>
```

Component A

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h3>Contact Summary</h3>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">SNo#</th>
      <th scope="col">Business Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Contact Person</th>
      <th scope="col">Address</th>
      <th scope="col">Contact Number</th>
      <th scope="col">Category</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody v-if="contacts.length>0">
    <tr v-for="(contact,index) in contacts" :key="index">
      <th scope="row">{{index}}</th>
      <td>{{contact.businessName}}</td>
      <td>{{contact.contactPerson}}</td>
      <td>{{contact.address}}</td>
      <td>{{contact.contactNumber}}</td>
      <td>{{contact.selectedCategory}}</td>

    </tr>
   </tbody>
   <p v-else>No Records Found</p>
</table>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      contact: {
        businessName: null,
        contactPerson: null,
        address: null,
        contactNumber: null,
        selectedCategory: null
      }
    }
  },
  props:['contacts']
    }

</script>
<style scoped></style>
```

Comment: why dont use vuex for sharing data between components?

Comment: @Mohsen I am new to vuejs will definitely explore that out. But I am not sure what’s going wrong over here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Component A` you have `contacts` passed from `Component C`, in `Component C` you set `contacts` array with default value

```
contacts:[ {
        businessName: null,
        contactPerson: null,
        address: null,
        contactNumber: null,
        selectedCategory: null
      }],
```

So length of `contacts` is 1 `v-for` rendered default value you set